# Get Data Mining models name from server by DMX

Tags: c#, sql, ssas, data-mining, dmx-ssas

Does somebody know if there is a way to get the models names from the server by executing script (DMX)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM [$system].[DMSCHEMA_MINING_MODELS]
```